# Click to redirect user based on geolocation

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'd like to redirect a user to a specific HTML file upon clicking a button based on their location. 
Specifically - I'd like to get their location upon clicking a button and redirect them to the proper HTML file.

I got this code from w3c schools, but I'm clueless of what to do next.

```js
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
    //You have your locaton here
      console.log("Latitude: " + pos.coords.latitude +
        "Longitude: " + pos.coords.longitude);
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getLocation()">Get Location</button>
```

Comment: could you give some examples for locations? it will be country or city?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
window.location.replace("http://example.com");
```

or:

```
window.location.href = "http://example.com";
```

After you get the location (latitude and longitude) in your javascript function

Answer (score 0):

Give your button an id and then in your script do something similar to this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "www.site123.com";
    };
</script>
```

And add if statements in the function based on the variable for latitude and longitude